# If $∘∘ℎ= ∧ ∘ℎ∘=$ then must $ℎ∘∘=ℎ$?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, recurrence-relations, matrix-decomposition, function-and-relation-composition

If not, then What can be said of each $,,ℎ$ and are there any simpy-definable minimal conditions imposable upon one or more of the indexable functions that would ensure this symmetric closure? What about a more generalized linear string form of $_1∘_2∘…∘_=_1 ∧ _2∘…∘_∘_1=_2 ∧ ⋯ ∧ _{−1}∘_∘_1∘…∘_{−2}=_{−1}$ (i.e., does it $⇒ _∘_1∘…∘_{−1}=_$, orand other propert⟮ies⊕y⟯ of $⋀_{i=1}^(_)$ analogous to the short-exact-seq form ⋀(,,ℎ) ? What if every propositional conjunction $∧$ is converted homogeneously to an implication-arrow (one of everyplace either )$⇐,⇒,⇔$; the same uni- or bi- directionality)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but a counterexample to the title is $f = g = 0$ and $h = 1$ with $\circ$ defined to be ordinary multiplication (i.e., the category with one object whose morphisms are natural numbers and whose composition is multiplication).

Comment: @S.C. What if none of them de-facto nullary?

Comment: Another counterexample is integer addition with $f = g = 1$ and $h = -1$.

Comment: More generally, if $f$ is invertible, then $g \circ h = id$, so $g = f$ and $h = f^{-1}$, and so $h\circ f\circ g = f$. Since there are plenty of examples of invertible $f \ne f^{-1}$, counterexamples abound.